# Replacing one character with another in a string

Tags: excel, replace, extract, formula, delimiter

I have a data like below:

`A:B:C:D`

and I want to replace the `C` with data (say, `Z`) so that it may look like

`A:B:Z:D`

How can I do it?

Answer (score 44):

`=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"C","Z")`

Although I wasn't clear on whether you wanted `G` or `Z`, you mentioned `G` but your example output shows `Z`.

Answer (score -3):

If you have A:B:C:D in cell A1, then this works:

```
=CONCATENATE(MID(A1, 1, SEARCH(":", MID(A1, SEARCH(":", A1) + 1, LEN(A1) - SEARCH(":", A1) + 1)) + SEARCH(":", A1)), "Z", MID(MID(MID(A1, SEARCH(":", A1) + 1, LEN(A1) - SEARCH(":", A1) + 1), SEARCH(":", MID(A1, SEARCH(":", A1) + 1, LEN(A1) - SEARCH(":", A1) + 1)) + 1, LEN(MID(A1, SEARCH(":", A1) + 1, LEN(A1) - SEARCH(":", A1) + 1)) - SEARCH(":", MID(A1, SEARCH(":", A1) + 1, LEN(A1) - SEARCH(":", A1) + 1)) + 1), SEARCH(":", MID(MID(A1, SEARCH(":", A1) + 1, LEN(A1) - SEARCH(":", A1) + 1), SEARCH(":", MID(A1, SEARCH(":", A1) + 1, LEN(A1) - SEARCH(":", A1) + 1)) + 1, LEN(MID(A1, SEARCH(":", A1) + 1, LEN(A1) - SEARCH(":", A1) + 1)) - SEARCH(":", MID(A1, SEARCH(":", A1) + 1, LEN(A1) - SEARCH(":", A1) + 1)) + 1)), LEN(MID(MID(A1, SEARCH(":", A1) + 1, LEN(A1) - SEARCH(":", A1) + 1), SEARCH(":", MID(A1, SEARCH(":", A1) + 1, LEN(A1) - SEARCH(":", A1) + 1)) + 1, LEN(MID(A1, SEARCH(":", A1) + 1, LEN(A1) - SEARCH(":", A1) + 1)) - SEARCH(":", MID(A1, SEARCH(":", A1) + 1, LEN(A1) - SEARCH(":", A1) + 1)) + 1))))
```

I know it's incredibly convoluted but it works.

EDIT: And to be clear, you'd replace "Z" with the data you want to add in.