# Excel VBA - Convert Date String to Date

Tags: excel, vba

I have a number of strings in cells which are dates but they need to be converted to date format.

They are in the following format:

```
mmm dd, yyyy
```

For Example:

```
Feb 10, 2016
```

So they can be 11 or 12 in length:

```
Feb 1, 2016
```

I have started writing a function to parse each part of the string individually (day as integer, month as integer and year as integer) to then convert into date format.

Firstly, is there an easier/slicker way to do this than the above?

If there isn't an easier way, what's the best was to convert the 3 letter month (e.g. Feb or Mar or Apr) into a month number (e.g. 2 or 3 or 4)? As that is the only bit I'm really stuck with.

Comment: format("Feb 10, 2016","dd mm yyyy")

Comment: Is the existing data _actually_ a date, or a string that looks like a date?

Comment: You might want to have a look at the following post for a more elaborate answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37100821/change-date-format-using-substitute-or-replace/37101358#37101358

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In VBA you could use:  `cdate("Feb 10, 2016")`.
As a function this would be:

```
Public Function ConvertToDate(rng As Range) As Date

    ConvertToDate = CDate(rng)

End Function
```

Comment: Why not just use `CDate(rng)` directly?

Comment: @arcadeprecinct because you can't call VBA functions from the worksheet - they have to be wrapped in a UDF like this.

Comment: Not sure what you mean @arcadeprecinct, or am I missing something? As a UDF I'm not sure you could shorten it any further.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I didn't think of calling it from a worksheet so I thought there was no need for a UDF

Answer (score 2):

Use a `Date` variable to read the value and then use the `Format` function to format the date as you see fit.

For example:

```
Sub test()
    Dim D As Date
    D = Range("A1").Value
    MsgBox Format(D, "mm/dd/yyyy")
End Sub
```

If I run the code with the string "Feb 10, 2016" in A1 then "02/10/2016" is displayed in the message box

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Sub test()
    MsgBox Month(Datevalue("Feb 10, 2016"))
End Sub
```

This will give: `2`

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need VBA? Excel provides you with a Text to Date function `=DATEVALUE()` and it does recognize *Feb 10, 2016*.

Comment: Are you sure of that?  I tried it before leaving my answer and it returned a `#VALUE!` error.  Admittedly the help file for the function states:  _Using the default date system in Microsoft Excel for Windows, the date_text argument must represent a date between January 1, 1900 and December 31, 9999_.  Using the format (and date) they've used I get the error with `=DATEVALUE("January 1, 1900")`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook It will depend on your regional settings. In the UK that format wouldn't be recognised.

Comment: ah, ok.  Cheers Rory - that'll be why it wasn't recognised then.