# Excel How to convert datetime into only date - m/d/YYYY format

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Date column has date and time in different formats.

```
05-09-14 21:58
11-08-13 11:56
08/19/2016 11:08:46
11-08-13 11:56
11-08-13 12:16
05/24/2014 08:26:06
08/24/2016 11:00:29
12/20/2014 09:16:19
08/25/2016 09:38:22
08/24/2016 10:59:05
08/25/2016 12:36:33
08/19/2016 10:38:37
11-08-13 14:53
11-08-13 16:18
11-08-13 13:38
10-10-13 16:14
11-08-13 12:44
08/31/2016 17:13:57
```

I'm trying to convert these datetime into only date m/d/YYYY format.
I tried =TEXT(cellofdate, "m/d/YYYY") but i'm still getting time for some entries.

Comment: Are you sure that all of these entries are real dates? Maybe these are just cells with text (looking like dates). You might want to read through this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37100821/change-date-format-using-substitute-or-replace/37101358#37101358 and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38000194/difference-between-date-and-time-w-out-work-week-excel/38001028#38001028

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. In the file i have, some of them are real dates and some of them are just text that looks like dates. when i convert the real date fields to general and remove the number after the dot, i get only the date. but how do i separate the text one's?

Answer (score 18):

A date is just a number.
To the left of the decimal place is the date, to the right is the time.

`=INT(A1)` will return the whole number.
Your first example will display as `05/09/2014 00:00`.  All you need to do now is format the cell as a date without the time.

**Edit:** And read the post that @Ralph linked to - very informative.

Answer (score 2):

If your concerned cell is `A1`, you can use the following expression :

```
  =DATEVALUE(MONTH(A1) & "/" & DAY(A1) & "/" & YEAR(A1))
```

Comment: Whether this works or not, depends on your _locale_ settings.

Answer (score 1):

This formula will construct the date, using the `DATE(year, month, day)`-function.

`=DATE(YEAR(B2), MONTH(B2), DAY(B2))`.