# Cannot retrieve display text in the cell when read excel via soapUI

Tags: excel

I am trying to extract formatted date time cell values into SoapUI DataSource.
Formatted value is displayed correctly.

Custome format `yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh:mm:ss.000"+10:00"`

[image]

Retrive value  : `42665`

Problem is I am not getting the display value after retrieval. What could be the possible issue.

Comment: Try to retrieve the `.Text` and not the `.Value`.

Comment: @Ralph In SoapUI dataSource control default is value

Comment: If you cannot grab the formatted value but merely the value then you'll have to do the formatting in `soapUI`. The value is correct as all dates and times in Excel are numbers. `42665` is the 42,665th day after December 31, 1899. Since this is a whole number (without decimals) the time `00:00:00` is assumed. For more information you might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37100821/change-date-format-using-substitute-or-replace/37101358#37101358 OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38000194/difference-between-date-and-time-w-out-work-week-excel/38001028#38001028