# Excel - subtract two date

Tags: excel, date

I have two date in twocolumn (Foramt cell - date)

```
 Column A        Column B
 30.12.2016        2.1.2017
```

I need to substract two date and get result

I try this

```
=DATEDIF(A1,B1,"d")
```

but return me   #VALUE.

I want to get numbers of days

Any idea?

Comment: The number of days

Comment: Are the cells definitely formatted as dates and not strings?

Comment: Yes, cells formatted as date

Comment: why not just `=B1-A1` ?

Comment: I try but still get #VALUE

Comment: How to format result column

Comment: Are you sure that both cells contain dates and not merely text which looks like dates? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37100821/change-date-format-using-substitute-or-replace/37101358#37101358

Comment: If you merely changed the format, after Excel initially interpreted the input as a text string, that will **NOT** change the data type from text to date.  Also, unless your system is using the dot as a date separator, it will interpret your input as text no matter how you format it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works if you use `comma` or `dash` or `slash` within the dates. 

Like this: `30,12,2016` or `30-12-2016` or `30/12/2016`

And also like this: `30,Dec,2016` or `30-Dec-2016` or `30/Dec/2016`

See this:

[image: ImageExplanation]