# How can I count using a time reference?

Tags: excel, time, reference

I am trying to count objects in a list (the list is in a different tab) based on different criteria. As it can be seen in the image uploaded, the criteria are:

1. Object name
2. Date
3. Time
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FFVO.png)
   I have a problem with the third one. How can I count the objects that occur between 13:30 and 14:00. I want to count the occurrences just by referencing to the time in the cells C5, D5, E5 etc. How can I do it?

Comment: If the times in row 5 are true times then you can use the functions `SumIfs()` with multiple if-criteria and `Hour()` to extract the hour of a time / date from a cell. Then you can sum / count all occurrences where the hour is between 13 and 14. Alternatively, you can also calculate the time fraction for 13:30 which is `0.56` and 14:00 which is `0.58` and sum / count all of those where the fraction is between 0.56 and 0.58. For more information about time / dates you might be interested to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38001028/1153513 OR http://stackoverflow.com/a/37101358/1153513

Comment: I see a clear answer here.. really looking forward to see how the 'solved' "count objects in a list" formula from OP looks like..  ( :

Answer (score 0):

Just use :

```
=countifs([urRange1],[urCriteria],[urTime],">=XXX",[urTime],"<YYYY")
```

with XXX is the value you get from =value(C5)
and YYY is the value you get from =value(D5)

Looking forward for OP verification.. ( :