# Excel VBA - How to convert 12:00:00 AM time to decimal/number?

Tags: vba, excel, datetime

I can't figure out how to convert 12:00:00 AM to number/decimal. I tried to convert the Time Format to "Short Time" or "h.mm" but it didn't work and it still returns 0.

```
Dim dbConvertTime as Double
Dim dtTime as Date

dtTime = Format("12:00:00 AM","Short Time")
dbConvertTime = (dtTime * 24)
```

*Output
dbConvertTime = 0

I wanted convert the Time(12:00:00) to 24:00:00 because this data(12:00:00) returns 0 when multiplied by 24. The output should be  = 576.00

Comment: You might want to read through this to better understand dates / times in Excel: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37101358/1153513 This is probably also a good read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38001028/1153513 Afterwards, you'll come to understand that **any** number with no decimal places (so, a zero after the decimal point) can be interpreted as a date / time and will always equal to `12:00:00 AM`.

Answer (score 0):

Will return the hour of a timestamp

```
Hour(Now())
```

This will return a 24 hour format timestamp. If you want a 12 hour format you could do the following:

```
dtTime = IIf(Hour(tme) > 12 Or Hour(tme) = 0, Abs(Hour(tme) - 12), Hour(tme))
```

I've used `abs` here to return 12 for when time is 12 AM

Comment: With my best feelings - don't you think, that the most used spreadsheet solution worldwide would have something better than a custom formula for a trivial task like converting time? - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx

Comment: @Vityata There is more than one way to skin a cat. Also NumberFormat as the OP stated won't return 12 when the time is "12:00:00 AM". Where as the above will. Also this is hardly a custom formula when everything is standard functionality that is available in both vba and worksheet functions