# Concatenate date with text in excel (norsk locale)

Tags: excel, date

i have an excel sheet with a date column, format is dd.mm.yyyy, locale is norwegian(bokmal). When i concatenate that with other columns, excel sheet shows an error.
I tried the following:
TEXT(A2,"mm.dd.yyy"()) -> excel shows an error 
CONCAT(B2,TEXT(A2,"mm.dd.yyy"()) -> excel shows an error.
ANy idea ?
I think the problem is due to non english locale.
[image]

Comment: `=TEXT(A2,"mm.dd.yyy")`? Why the extra parentheses?

Comment: typo, sorry about that. This is what i typed: =TEXT(A2,"dd.mm.yyyy")

Comment: Please have a look at the following two posts and see if that resolves your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37100821/change-date-format-using-substitute-or-replace/37101358#37101358 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38000194/difference-between-date-and-time-w-out-work-week-excel/38001028#38001028